# Invoke-WebRequest with a hex value

Tags: powershell, curl

I'm trying to curl a payload containing a semi-colon however it fails

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Body '{"text" : "foo;"}' -Method Post

Invoke-WebRequest: {"id":"model.incoming_hook.parse_data.app_error","message":"Unable to parse incoming data","detailed_error":"","request_id":"3papdgjsni87untfo7e3rsogpy","status_code":400}
```

but

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Body '{"text" : "foo"}' -Method Post
```

works fine. I have converted the semi colon to be %3B and this seems to post as ;. My problem then is it converts all %2F strings into slashes - which then break (it needs to be the literal 2F value for some reason).

When using the curl command or in python it's fine, so it's not as if the endpoint is not accepting the ';' value. I have tried single quotes, double quotes, convertto-json, slashes etc. and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Tried [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) yet? It's a little more flexible since it's geared towards API use. Notably, it will allow you to use hashtables rather than build JSON manually, which can aid readability.

Comment: Same error: `Invoke-RestMethod: {"id":"model.incoming_hook.parse_data.app_error","message":"Unable to parse incoming data","detailed_error":"","request_id":"zfuhmx14upniiea55bkn6fg4ke","status_code":400}`

Comment: My bad, `Invoke-RestMethod` doesn't appear to auto-convert to JSON either. However, `Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost" -Body ( @{text="foo;"} | ConvertTo-Json ) -Method Post -ContentType "application/json"` works for me, as does `Invoke-RestMethod "http://localhost" -Body '{"text" : "foo;"}' -Method Post -ContentType "application/json"`. My bet would be the missing `Content-Type` that's tripping you up (you get `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default on a POST).

Comment: Can you post an example of the problematic body with slashes in? If I do this: ```invoke-webrequest -uri "http://example.org" -body '{"text" : "foo;/"}' -method Post``` or this: ```invoke-webrequest -uri "http://example.org" -body '{"text" : "foo%3B%2F"}'``` -method Post it posts the literal string ```{"text" : "foo;/"}``` or ```{"text" : "foo%3B%2F"}``` in the body

Comment: My problem is I can't send %2F as a string it always gets converted to / - but in this case I need the literal value %2F - on the flipside I couldn't get a semi-colon to work at all UNLESS I passed it to %3B but in doing that it. I don't want to convert `%2F` I need it sent verbatim. In your example my return is: `"foo;/"` when I would want `"foo;%2F"`

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but, do you mean the server is url-decoding the body, and you want the *decoded* body to contain the string ```%2F```? In which case, you might need to url-encode the ```%``` as ```%25``` - e.g. your literal string```"%2F"``` becomes ```"%252F"``` so your decoded string ends up as ```%2F``` again on the server? If that works, there's classes that can help with the encoding, but let's check if that's what you want first...

Comment: Yea looks like %252F is what I needed. Thanks.   Edit: Is there a `--data-urlencode` equivalent in powershell?

Comment: You can pass the contents to `[System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlEncode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bring together all the information in the coments, there's a few options, depending on what content types your server accepts.

**Content-Type: application/json**

If it accepts `Content-Type: application/json` you can use @Jeroen Mostert's answer in the comments:

```bsh
# raw text in a hashtable
$data = @{ "text" = "foo;%2F" };

# convert to json
$json = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $data -Compress;

# post as 'application/json'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.org" -Body $json -Method "POST" -ContentType "application/json";
```

which will send the following HTTP request:

```
POST http://example.org/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-GB) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.19041.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: example.org
Content-Length: 18
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"text":"foo;%2F"}
```

**Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

By default, PowerShell will post data using `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so you can send your text as follows:

```bsh
# raw text in a hashtable
$data = @{ "text" = "foo;%2F" };

# convert to json
$json = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $data -Compress;

# url-encode
$body = [System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlEncode($json);

# post as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.org" -Body $body -Method "POST";
```

which will send the following HTTP request:

```
POST http://example.org/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-GB) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.19041.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: example.org
Content-Length: 36
Connection: Keep-Alive

%7B%22text%22%3A%22foo%3B%252F%22%7D
```

Note - the full json text is url-encoded, but maybe that's not what your server expects.

**Custom encoding**

If for some reason your server wants the raw json syntax, but the contents of the `text` property needs to be url-encoded you can do some custom encoding like this:

```bsh
# raw text in a hashtable
$data = @{
    "text" = "foo;%2F"
};

# url-encode the text
$data.text = [System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlEncode($data.text);

# convert to json
$json = ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $data -Compress;

# post as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://example.org" -Body $json -Method "POST";
```

which will generate the HTTP request:

```
POST http://example.org/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-GB) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.19041.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: example.org
Content-Length: 22
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"text":"foo%3B%252F"}
```

Hopefully one of these will work for you. If not, there should be enough snippets above to put something together that does :-).